# CakePHP Model FK Joins

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I'm having trouble getting Cake to join on the correct foreign keys. Below is the current SQL that Cake produces.

```sql
SELECT
    "AirtimeShowInstance"."id" AS "AirtimeShowInstance__id",
    "AirtimeShowInstance"."starts" AS "AirtimeShowInstance__starts",
    "AirtimeShowInstance"."ends" AS "AirtimeShowInstance__ends",
    "AirtimeShowInstance"."show_id" AS "AirtimeShowInstance__show_id",
    ...
    "AirtimeShow"."id" AS "AirtimeShow__id",
    ...
FROM
    "public"."cc_show_instances" AS "AirtimeShowInstance" 
LEFT JOIN
    "public"."cc_show" AS "AirtimeShow" 
        ON (
            "AirtimeShow"."id" = "AirtimeShowInstance"."id"
        ) 
WHERE
    1 = 1 
ORDER BY
    "AirtimeShowInstance"."starts" DESC
```

If I change the join parameter manually from 
`("AirtimeShow"."id" = "AirtimeShowInstance"."id")`
to 
`("AirtimeShow"."id" = "AirtimeShowInstance"."show_id")` it works fantastically!

What's wrong with my Models? :(

AirtimeShowInstance.php

```
class AirtimeShowInstance extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'cc_show_instances';

    public $hasOne = array('AirtimeShow' => array(
        'className' => 'AirtimeShow',
        'foreignKey' => 'id'
    ));

}
```

AirtimeShow.php

```
class AirtimeShow extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'cc_show';

    public $hasMany = array('AirtimeShowInstance' => array(
        'className' => 'AirtimeShowInstance',
        'foreignKey' => 'show_id'
    ));


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you are using the wrong assocciation type, you must use a `belongsTo` one instead of a `hasOne`.

And the name of the foreign key for the `belongsTo` association config must be `show_id` too, `id` is not a foreign key, it's the reference in the other model/table.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Models > Associations: Linking Models Together > hasOne](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasone)**
- **[Cookbook > Models > Associations: Linking Models Together > belongsTo](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#belongsto)**

Comment: Thanks NDM. 

I'd tried that solution already - However Cake reports that that the column doesn't exist (because it doesn't!)

`Error: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column AirtimeShow.show_id does not exist LINE 1: ...LEFT JOIN "public"."cc_show" AS "AirtimeShow" ON ("AirtimeSh... ^`

Comment: @ScottRobinson It's a little late, I didn't payed enough attention. Actually you should use a `belongsTo` association, as the docs state, in a `hasOne` association the _other_ model has the foreign key.